# rootScope is upating on scope variable update

Tags: angularjs, scope, rootscope

I have created a rootScope variable like

```
$rootScope.globalData = data;
$rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value = "ST";    //Default Value
$scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value = 1;                      //Default Value
```

where `data` is my returning value from api. Also create a scope variable which is a object contains a list of items.

```
$scope.chillerAttributes = data.ObjCandidateListChillerAttributes;
$scope.chillerConditions = data.ObjCandidateListConditions;
```

On HTML I have:

```
<select ng-model="chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value" style="width:53%;" ng-options="item.Id as item.Description for item in ValidRatingHeatSource" ng-change="heatSourceChanged()" id="ddRatingHeatSource" class="form-control search-select designComboboxHeight" data-container="body"></select>
```

Here `ValidRatingHeatSource` is

```
$scope.ValidRatingHeatSource = \*list of items*\
```

On change of Drop Down I have written an function. In that

```
if($scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value == 2)
{
  $rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value = "HW";
}
else
{
  $rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value = "ST";
}
```

Till now was the my current code.
Issue is :

When the above function is called then whenever current `$rootScope` varible i.e. `$rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value` is changed to `"HW"` or `"ST"` it also changing `$scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value` to `"HW"` or `"ST"`.

Why so?

Is there any inbuilt functionality in angularjs?
Please suggest if I am making any mistake? New suggestion are also welcome.

Comment: The `ng-model` (`chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value`) maybe is attached to both `$scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value` and `$rootScope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value`. So when the select changes so does the variable attached to `ng-model`. Not sure about this but it could be worth a try re-naming the `$scope` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is the way JavaScript works and has nothing to do with AngularJS. JavaScript is an object-oriented (prototype-based) language where objects are addressed by reference and not by value. E.g. assign car2 to car1 and both of them will reference the same object ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reimavronicolas/g68cbom6/))

```
var car1 = {make: "Audi"}
var car2 = car1;
car2.make = "Toyota";
```

So in your case, `$rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource` and `$scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource` are the same object.

Rather, it seems like you want to create a copy. You can do so with [angular.Copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
$scope.chillerAttributes = angular.copy(data.ObjCandidateListChillerAttributes);
$scope.chillerConditions = angular.copy(data.ObjCandidateListConditions);
```

Comment: I understood the JSfiddel example. Right now I am not marking as Accepted, but as soon as I resolve the issue will mark it as Accpted Ans. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your example u have both ng-model and ng-change, so:
1. User change value in select.
2. $scope.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value changes (ng-model)
3. heatSourceChanged  starts (ng-change) -> $rootScope.globalData.chillerConditions.HeatSource.Value changes

So everything works as should...

Comment: Your ans is explanation of above ans. +1